# Finding most common non-null prefix per group in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to write a structured query that finds the most common not-null PREFIX (occurences) per UNIQUE_GUEST_ID.
There is input data:

```
val inputDf = Seq(
  (1, "Mr"),
  (1, "Mme"),
  (1, "Mr"),
  (1, null),
  (1, null),
  (1, null),
  (2, "Mr"),
  (3, null)).toDF("UNIQUE_GUEST_ID", "PREFIX")
println("Input:")
inputDf.show(false)
```

My solution was:

```
inputDf
  .groupBy($"UNIQUE_GUEST_ID")
  .agg(collect_list($"PREFIX").alias("PREFIX"))
```

But that is not what i need:
Expected:

```
+---------------+------+
|UNIQUE_GUEST_ID|PREFIX|
+---------------+------+
|1              |Mr    |
|2              |Mr    |
|3              |null  |
+---------------+------+
```

Actual:

```
+---------------+-------------+
|UNIQUE_GUEST_ID|PREFIX       |
+---------------+-------------+
|1              |[Mr, Mme, Mr]|
|3              |[]           |
|2              |[Mr]         |
+---------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```scala
 val inputDf = Seq(
      (1, "Mr"),
      (1, "Mme"),
      (1, "Mr"),
      (1, null),
      (1, null),
      (1, null),
      (2, "Mr"),
      (3, null)).toDF("UNIQUE_GUEST_ID", "PREFIX")
    println("Input:")
    inputDf.show(false)
    /**
      * Input:
      * +---------------+------+
      * |UNIQUE_GUEST_ID|PREFIX|
      * +---------------+------+
      * |1              |Mr    |
      * |1              |Mme   |
      * |1              |Mr    |
      * |1              |null  |
      * |1              |null  |
      * |1              |null  |
      * |2              |Mr    |
      * |3              |null  |
      * +---------------+------+
      */

    inputDf
      .groupBy($"UNIQUE_GUEST_ID", $"PREFIX").agg(count($"PREFIX").as("count"))
      .groupBy($"UNIQUE_GUEST_ID")
      .agg(max( struct( $"count", $"PREFIX")).as("max"))
      .selectExpr("UNIQUE_GUEST_ID", "max.PREFIX")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---------------+------+
      * |UNIQUE_GUEST_ID|PREFIX|
      * +---------------+------+
      * |2              |Mr    |
      * |1              |Mr    |
      * |3              |null  |
      * +---------------+------+
      */
```

Comment: If i use this solution, i have error "Error:(758, 12) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
      .show(false)"

Comment: you are using all these operation on `Unit` not on the dataframe. check the creation of input dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
val df2 = inputDf.groupBy('UNIQUE_GUEST_ID,'PREFIX).agg(count('PREFIX).as("ct"))
val df3 = df2.groupBy('UNIQUE_GUEST_ID).agg(max('ct).as("ct"))
df2.join(df3,Seq("ct","UNIQUE_GUEST_ID")).show()
```

output:

```
+---+---------------+------+
| ct|UNIQUE_GUEST_ID|PREFIX|
+---+---------------+------+
|  1|              2|    Mr|
|  0|              3|  null|
|  2|              1|    Mr|
+---+---------------+------+
```